# How can I sort a list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code [here is the code and what should be the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef9pR.png)

Can anyone help me how I can solve this code with a for loop?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by extracting the `names` field for each user.

```py
user_names = [dict["names"] for dict in users]
```